# Issue is consuming speech to text service using GCP service

Tags: c#, google-cloud-functions, speech-to-text

I subscribed to Google speech to text service in GCP and trying to convert audio files to text using C#.

When I try to send Audio file from local using audio transcription request code provided by Google, Getting error:
StatusCode=InvalidArgument, Detail="Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes

Added the audio file to Bucket storage and used Transcribing long audio files code facing an error Getting error:
StatusCode=ResourceExhausted, Detail="Quota exceeded for quota metric 'speech.googleapis.com/default_requests' and limit 'DefaultRequestsPerMinutePerProject' of service 'speech.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:764086051850

I have installed Cloud SDK shell, created a service account in IAM, Added it to the project, downloaded JSON key, Set Google application credential but nothing works.

Comment: Send smaller files? The errors seem fairly clear.

Comment: Boss I am sending an 10 sec audio. And even tried with 5 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is a common one with the Speech-To-Text and has already been answered on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51601697/invalid-argument-request-payload-size-exceeds-the-limit-10485760-bytes).

You also need to ensure you have enabled and/or associated a billing account to your Speech-To-Text API within the associated project as there are associated [fees](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/#cloud-speech-to-text-api-pricing) with using this API.

If you have already enabled billing, you most likely have reached the maximum daily [quota](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas) limit for the Speech-To-Text API. Daily quotas on certain APIs refresh at midnight PST/PDT. If you find the limit is too low, you will need to request a quota increase from the console which is subject to approval.